# Display Map Center based on created Points

Tags: javascript, google-maps

All,
I'm getting a couple points to create some markers in my data map. Here is my code to display the map:

```
var map;
var icon0;
var newpoints = new Array();

function addLoadEvent(func) { 
var oldonload = window.onload; 
if (typeof window.onload != 'function'){ 
    window.onload = func
} else { 
    window.onload = function() {
        oldonload();
        func();
    }
}
}

addLoadEvent(loadMap);

function loadMap() {
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
map.setCenter(new GLatLng( <?php echo $_SESSION['pav_event_latitude']; ?>, <?php echo $_SESSION['pav_event_longitude']; ?>), 12);
map.setMapType(G_NORMAL_MAP);

icon0 = new GIcon();
icon0.image = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png";
icon0.shadow = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png";
icon0.iconSize = new GSize(20, 34);
icon0.shadowSize = new GSize(37, 34);
icon0.iconAnchor = new GPoint(9, 34);
icon0.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(9, 2);
icon0.infoShadowAnchor = new GPoint(18, 25);

addPoints(myStores);
}

function addPoints( points )
{   
for ( var p = 0; p < points.length; ++p )
{
    var pointData = points[p];
    if ( pointData == null ) return; 
    var point = new GLatLng( pointData.latitude, pointData.longitude );
var marker = createMarker( point, icon0, pointData.html );
map.addOverlay( marker );
}
}

function createMarker(point, icon, popuphtml) {
var popuphtml = "<div id=\"popup\">" + popuphtml + "<\/div>";
var marker = new GMarker(point, icon);
GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(popuphtml);
});

function Store( lat, long, text )
{
this.latitude = lat;
this.longitude = long;
this.html = text;
}

var myStores = [<?php echo $jsData;?>, null];
```

What I would like to do is basically get the average of all of the points created so that can be the center of my map so it shows all of my points in the map instead of just a couple of them sometimes. Has anyone ever done something like this?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: If you want to show *all* points, why not set a bounding box instead of a center point?

Comment: @alex If I have multiple lat/long coordinates, how can I make sure that it fits them all in teh fitBounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [**google.maps.Map.fitBounds()**](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map)

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script> 
<script  type="text/javascript">
function addLoadEvent(func) { 
var oldonload = window.onload; 
if (typeof window.onload != 'function'){ 
    window.onload = func
} else { 
    window.onload = function() {
        oldonload();
        func();
    }
}
}

var map,
    infowin=new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'moin'});
function loadMap() 
{
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'),
    {   
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center:new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_SESSION['pav_event_latitude']; ?>, 
                                    <?php echo $_SESSION['pav_event_longitude']; ?>)
    });

  addPoints(myStores);
}

function addPoints( points )
{  
  var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for ( var p = 0; p < points.length; ++p )
  {
    var pointData = points[p];
    if ( pointData == null ) {map.fitBounds(bounds);return; }
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng( pointData.latitude, pointData.longitude );
    bounds.union(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(point));
    createMarker( point,  pointData.html );
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}

function createMarker(point,  popuphtml) 
{
  var popuphtml = "<div id=\"popup\">" + popuphtml + "<\/div>";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
      position:point,
      map:map
    }
  );
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowin.setContent(popuphtml)
      infowin.open(map,marker);
    });

}
function Store( lat, long, text )
{
this.latitude = lat;
this.longitude = long;
this.html = text;
}



var myStores = [<?php echo $jsData;?>, null];
addLoadEvent(loadMap);
</script>
```

Comment: @DrMolle If I have multiple lat/long coordinates, how can I make sure that it fits them all in teh fitBounds?

Comment: the example above will do it(the existing addPoints-function may be replaced by it). It takes a initial LatLngBounds and will extend it with every given point, the result will be a LatLngBounds-object with 2 points which defines a rectangle where all given points are placed in. this resulting LatLngBounds pass as argument to fitBounds()

Comment: Thanks for that. However how do I update my loadMap() function so that it loads it the correct way. I tried to comment out the map.setCenter(new GLatLng( <?php echo $_SESSION['pav_event_latitude']; ?>, <?php echo $_SESSION['pav_event_longitude']; ?>), 12) but they it didn't display the map.

Comment: You dont need to modify loadMap() . When you wan't the initial center of the map also to be a part of bounds, provide `map.getCenter()` as argument to the initial bounds (I've applied this in the code above.)

Comment: That works better, however I do have one question additional question. How can I set the zoom based on this? Right now I have it set to 11 but if they all fall in closer to my map center, can I zoom it in closer?

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses however it isn't doing that. It basically keeps it at zoom level 11 or 12 based on whatever I say in my map.setCenter.

Comment: Oh, I you use Gmap2, my code is GMap3, please give me a moment,

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not opposed to going to GMap3 but just not sure how to update my code to get there...

Comment: Updated the code above, it's all V3 now(note the different file to include, no key required anymore)

Comment: Thank you very much! That works so well! Appreciate the help!